# ContentTools tutorial: undefined element on function parameters

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am testing the wysiwyg editor ContentTools and I have to admit is fantastic. Unfortunately the tutorials are "dry" and all with coffeescript (which might be an advantage for who knows it). My problem right now is that the tutorials are not 100% bugfree (as the author said somewhere) and don't provide an archive with them working.
So right now I'm stuck with one of the basics: add a new tool to the toolbar.

The error I get is:

> content-tools.js:10516 Uncaught ReferenceError: element is not defined

which points to the trivial

```
 TimeTool.getDatetime(element, selection)(function() {
```

The time-tool.coffee I created is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/whpm78dg/) and the tutorial is [here](http://getcontenttools.com/tutorials/adding-new-tools).
One of the big drawbacks of ContentTools is that the additional tools need to be compiled in the library (at least that's what I understood), so the jsfiddle can't link to a CDN-ed version of ContentTools.

How could it be possible to get an object not defined on the parameters of a function?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with changing

```
@getDatetime(element, selection) ->
```

to

```
@getDatetime: (element, selection) ->
```

This makes it in the same syntax as the apply function - and actually works.. :O